# class diagram for changes without new class/method?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

A new feature has been requested in my project where all changes are in existing classes and methods. Basically I don't have to create any new
method or class in the existing project.

My question is does it make sense to create a class diagram for changes when there is no addition of class or method?

Comment: If there's nothing new, and method return types / parameter types are the same, what is there for you to change in the class diagram?

Answer (score 1):

A diagram in UML is a way to communicate a (part of) model to your audience.

You create diagrams if you consider them helpful in this communication.

So if the diagram will help your audience understand which changes you made, then YES, it makes sense. Otherwise the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the Boy Scout principle and leave things better than you found them. It's no fun to be the new guy on a complex project.